# Boost signals - type passed as parameter

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-signals

I found this C++ code that uses boost signals and I'm trying to understand it.

```
// A boost::signal wrapper structure 
template <typename Signature>
struct SignalBase : public boost::noncopyable
{
    typedef boost::function_traits< Signature >        SignatureTraits;

    typedef boost::signal<Signature>                   SignalType;
    typedef typename SignalType::slot_function_type    SlotFunctionType;
    typedef typename SignalType::result_type           ResultType;
    typedef boost::signals::connection                 ConnectionType;

    SignalBase() : m_signal() {};
    virtual ~SignalBase() {};

protected:
    SignalType m_signal;
};


// I use a specialization of this template for an arity of 1.
// The template generates the correct function call operator for the arity of the signal.
template<int Arity, typename Signature>
struct SelArity : public SignalBase<Signature> {};

// Specialization
template<typename Signature>
struct SelArity< 1, Signature> : public SignalBase<Signature>
{
    typedef SignalBase<Signature> BaseType;
    inline typename BaseType::ResultType operator()(typename BaseType::SignatureTraits::arg1_type arg )
    {
        return BaseType::m_signal( arg );
    }
};
```

I can't figure out what `SelArity` functors will return. As far as I understand `m_signal` is a type which can declare signals that will be able to connect to functions with `Signature` signature. How is it possible to have types as parameters?( see `return BaseType::m_signal( arg );` ) What is the type represented by `ResultType` ? And how will I be able to use the object returned by `SelArity` functor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `m_signal` is not a type, it's an instance of class `SignalType`, which is `boost::signal<Signature>`.

`SelArity` functor actually invokes `m_signal` with 1 argument and returns its return value.

(What all these wrappers are needed for I don't know.)

Comment: what about `arg`? is `arg` also an instance? also i read the boost documentation and if the `SignalType` is right(if Signature is for example `void(float)` ) calling the signal object won't need any parameters e.g.<br/> `boost::signal<void (float)> sig;`<br/> `sig.connect(&print);`<br/>`sig(5);`<br/> So why do i need to return a `SignalType` object(which is `m_signal`) with one parameter? Doesn't `m_signal` translate in this example to `sig`? So why should `m_signal` be invoked with arguments?

Comment: @John Smith 1) Yes, `arg` is the argument (of type `BaseType::SignatureTraits::arg1_type`). 2) If signal's signature is `void(float)`, the caller must invoke it with one argument: `sig(5.0)`. 3) The functor doesn't return the signal object, it *invokes* it, and returns its return value (see "combiners" in the documentation). 4) The last, but not the least: I highly recommend you to read a book on C++ basics! It's crucial to understand more advanced topics.